# Erlang - lists transformation

Tags: list, erlang

I would like some help, please.
I have a list of users and their invoices. There can be many users and each user can have many invoices.
So, I would like to go from `[{user, invoice}]` to `[{user, [invoice]}]`.

For example, convert this...

```
[{user1, invoice11}, {user1, invoice12}, {user2, invoice21}, {user2, invoice22}].
```

Into this...

```
[{user1, [invoice11, invoice12]}, {user2, [invoice21, invoice22]}].
```

Comment: Is the initial list ordered by user?

Comment: Yes sir, it is. By user and by invoice

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `fold()` to create a `dict` and then make it a list:

```
UsersInvoices = [{user1, invoice11}, {user1, invoice12},
                 {user2, invoice21}, {user2, invoice22}].

dict:to_list(lists:foldl(fun({User, Invoice}, D) ->
                             dict:append(User, Invoice, D) end,
                         dict:new(), UsersInvoices)).
```

Comment: I'm going to give it a try. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You don`t need to use folds or dictionaries. Assuming they are sorted by users you could do this. It also keeps the list sorted.

```
convert([{U, I}|R])->convert(R,[{U,[I]}]).
convert([], RL)->lists:reverse(RL);
convert([{U, I}|R], [{U,IL}|RL])->convert(R, [{U, [I|IL]}|RL]);
convert([{U1, I}|R], [{U2, IL} |RL])->convert(R, [{U1, [I]}|[{U2, lists:reverse(IL)}|RL]]).
```

Comment: Glad i could help. Would you please mark this as the correct answer, for other people who are looking for the answer.